# How to debug SSH port forwarding?

Tags: linux, port-forwarding

The problem I encountered here is weird. There are two ubuntu linux machines, two identical HTTP servers run on them. One is ok on port forwarding, the other gets ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

I've checked ufw settings but found nothing, since I can do SSH login on any of them, it should be enough for port forwarding. So, any suggestion to debugging this problem? Thank you in advance.

FYI, I did the test: 
On the server, Port forwarding is 64444:localhost:64444.

`# nc -vv -l 64444    // Got nothing.`

On the client, run:

`# nc -vv localhost 64444
 myhost [127.0.0.1] 64444 (?) open
 sent 0, rcvd 0: NOTSOCK`

`# nc -vv localhost 64441  // any other port
 myhost [127.0.0.1] 64441 (?): connection refused
 sent 0, rcvd 0: NOTSOCK`

Answer (score 0):

Oh! I see the problem.

In one server, /etc/ssh/sshd_config has the line below that will drop forward connection directly.

`AllowTcpForwarding no`

After I remove this line and restart sshd, this problem is solved.